# Rails: Finding max of array that may contain nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given:

```
shipping_costs = {
  key1: 45,
  key2: 99,
  key3: nil,
  key4: 24
}
```

What's the cleanest way to get the max of those keys assuming nil = 0?

If I run a straight `shipping_costs.values.max` in the Rails console I get this:

```
ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with nil failed
```

Cleanest way to turn those nils into zeros before running max?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'd go for:

```
shipping_costs.values.map(&:to_i).max
```

`nil.to_i` is `0`.

Comment: Most technically correct and specific to the question, so you get the answer. I'll probably do Tom's solution though. :)

Comment: There is an potential bug source here, which is that this will return a max of zero for the array [nil, -2, -4, -1], when you presumably want -1. For this reason I would prefer the solution of @toniedzwiedz.

Comment: The question did specify though that `nil` values should be assumed to be `= 0`.

Comment: Another limitation is that this attempts to convert the non-nil values to integers, too, which will be problematic if there are decimal values in there or other types such as  strings or dates. The question did not ask for that!

Answer (score 45):

If you want to keep it really concise, you can use
`shipping_costs.values.compact.max`

The [`compact`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-compact) method removes all `nil` values from an array.

The other answers are also good ideas. However, I'd prefer to reject the values instead of replacing them with numbers. I thinks it's better to know an array only contains `nil` values than to guess where a 0 (or whatever value you choose) came from.

Comment: Good, clean answer! I will have to check for nil if ALL of the values end up being nil. `[].max` => nil.

Comment: @JamonHolmgren I thinks it's better to know it only contains `nil` values instead of guessing where a `0` came from ;)

Comment: it's good to know about the `compact` method. Now I can stop writing `reject(&:nil?)` all the time

Answer (score 8):

Nobody has mentioned even shorter form?,

```
shipping_costs.values.max_by(&:to_i)
```

(Just an info)

Comment: This variant will give slightly better but still potentially incorrect results if there are decimal values in the list.

Answer (score 7):

[`max`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) takes a block, allowing you to do a comparison, similar to how `sort` works:

```
[45, 99, nil, 24].max{ |a,b| (a || 0) <=> (b || 0) }
=> 99
```

or:

```
[45, 99, nil, 24].max{ |a,b| a.to_i <=> b.to_i }
=> 99
```

This lets you coerce the value how you want/need, before the comparison occurs.

For your case, `shipping_costs.values` will return the array you need to compare, so:

```
shipping_costs.values.max{ |a,b| a.to_i <=> b.to_i }
```

Comment: This won't work for an array containing only negative values, in case of which `nil` will be returned as the maximum element (`nil.to_i` returns 0). However, in this specific case, the array contains *costs* so it's hard to expect a negative value to come up. +1

Comment: Besides getting rid of nil values with `Array#compact` I think this is a good answer because you can decide what do to with the `nil` values.
You could for example instead of assigning `0` to it, use `Float::INFINITY` or `-Float::INFINITY` to bias how they are treated.

Answer (score 4):

Do `shipping_costs.values.reject {|v| v.nil? }.max`

Comment: `reject` is cleaner then a `select` combined with a `not`. `compact` is more concise, but all of this fails when all fixnums are negative and nil is the max.

Comment: thanks. I knew there was something like that but never used it

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu compact does not fail on negative numbers, it just removes the nil values and selects the negative with lowest absolute value.

Comment: Yes @Tom, I guess my answer has the same effect of yours in this case. I just don't deleted because it can be interesting for someone else's problem.

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu I don't want you to delete it. It shows a similar but different approach and the concept can be applied to a multitude of functions, not just `nil` checking. It's a very good answer.

Comment: Just a remark that it can be condensed to `shipping_costs.values.reject(&:nil?).max`.

Answer (score 2):

To perform the operation actually requested in the question (replace nils with zeros before `max`), without messing with any other values, and assuming you don't have `false` as a possible value, you could do this:

```
shipping_costs.values.map { |x| x || 0 }.max
```

However, in real applications it will probably be simpler and better to follow the answer given by @toniedzwiedz.